# Every numerable principal $G$-bundle is regular over $SB$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

Studying [Fibre Bundles](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/husemoller) from Husemoller, I stumble across the following problem in chapter $8$.

***Definition:*** An open covering $\lbrace U_i \rbrace_{i \in S}$ of a topological space is numerable provided there exists a locally finite partition of unity $\lbrace u_i \rbrace_{i \in S}$ such that $\overline{u_i^{-1}(0,1]} \subset U_i$ for each $i \in  S$.

***Definition:*** A principal $G-$bundle $\xi$ over a space $B$ is numerable provided there is a numerable $\lbrace U_i \rbrace_{i \in S}$ of $B$ such that $\xi|U_i$ is trivial for each $i \in S$.

***Definition:*** A bundle $\xi$ over a suspension $SB = \frac{B \times [-1,1]}{B \times \lbrace -1 \rbrace \cup B \times \lbrace 1 \rbrace}$ us regular provided, for dome $\varepsilon > 0$, $\xi|B(-\varepsilon, 1]$ and $\xi|B[-1,\varepsilon)$ are trivial.

In the sentence following the latter definition the author states without explaining:

> Every numerable principal $G$-bundle is regular over $SB$.

Is this a straightfoward consequence? Requiring numerable means having an open covering and trivial restriction. Is there an easy way to glue them all and find $\varepsilon$ or another approach is needed?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: What do $B(-\varepsilon,1)$ and $B(-1,\varepsilon)$ mean?

Comment: @JackLee Is the restriction budle: for a bundle $\xi = (E,p,B)$, the bundle restriction to a subset $A \subseteq B$, is the bundle $(p^{-1}(A),p,A)$

Comment: I understand that $\xi|B(-\varepsilon,1)$ means the restriction of $\xi$ to $B(-\varepsilon,1)$. But my question was what does $B(-\varepsilon,1)$ mean?

Comment: A numerable bundle over a contractible space is trivial. The two cones which make up the suspension are clearly contractible. (Note that the pullback/restriction of a numerable bundle is numerable)

Comment: @JackLee I’m sorry. I meant the image of $B \times (-\varepsilon,1)$ in the suspension.

Comment: Something's wrong here. As @Tyrone commented, the cones that make up the suspension (i.e., the images of $B\times [-1,1)$ and $B\times (-1,1]$) are contractible, and every numerable bundle over a contractible space is trivial. However, the image of $B\times (-\varepsilon,1)$ is homotopy equivalent to $B$, and not necessarily contractible. There's no reason why the bundle should be trivial over that subspace.

Comment: @JackLee Could you please expand? I don’t get it

Comment: The quotient map makes no nontrivial identifications in $B\times (-1,1)$, so if you restrict the quotient map to $B\times (-\varepsilon,1)$, it is a homeomorphism onto its image. Thus the subset you're calling $B(-\varepsilon,1)$ is homeomorphic to $B\times (-\varepsilon,1)$ and thus not necessarily contractible, so there's no reason why the restriction of $\xi$ to this set should be trivial. If we were talking about $B(-\varepsilon,1]$ and $B[-1,\varepsilon)$, then the bundle would be trivial over both of those.

Comment: @JackLee I made an edit, I was wrong about the points $1,-1$, which should be included in the definition of regular. Is it possible to properly answer the question now?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say in your question what the notations $B[-1,\varepsilon)$ and $B(-\varepsilon,1]$ mean, but as you noted in a comment, they stand for the images of $B\times [-1,\varepsilon)$ and $B\times (-\varepsilon,1]$ under the quotient map, respectively.

For any $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$, both of these sets are contractible: For example, the straight-line homotopy $H\colon B\times (-\varepsilon,1]\times [0,1]\to B\times (-\varepsilon,1]$ defined by $H((b,s), t) = (b,s+t(1-s))$ descends to the quotient to give a homotopy $\widetilde H\colon B(-\varepsilon,1]\times [0,1]\to B(-\varepsilon,1]$ satisfying $\widetilde H((\cdot,\cdot),0) = \text{Id}$ and $\widetilde H((\cdot,\cdot),1) = \text{constant}$.

As @Tyrone mentioned in a comment, every numerable bundle over a contractible space is trivial. (Corollary 10.3 in Husemoller's 3rd edition shows that every numerable principal bundle is trivial, and it follows that every fiber bundle is trivial by applying the corollary to the associated principal bundle.) Thus every numerable bundle over a suspension satisfies the regularity condition for each $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the precise and neat answer. I'm sorry for my mistake involving notation.